# Java to Android

Tags: java, jar, apk

I have developed an application (jar) based in Java Swing (JFrame) in Netbeans.

Is there an easy way to convert this application to an Android application (apk) in orden to publish it?

Comment: Thank you, I edited in order to have only one question

Comment: No, Java Swing, while officially still supported, is basically dead.  Android uses a very different UI framework and will not run Swing directly.

Comment: The simple answer is no. You may be able to reuse some of the application logic but you will have to re-implemented the UI using Androids UI framework. As long as your application is only supposed to do something when it is in foreground and you only use app-private storage the application logic should work an Android.

Comment: [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) is a new way for Swing.  But for your question No, The UI with Android is completely different as other have elaborate you can apply the logic of your application with some logic